# Reading negative values of accelerometer

Tags: c, accelerometer, negative-number

Im interfacing accelerometer with TivaC and displaying the RAW data on UART.

```
void main(){

  signed int accelerationX;

  accelerationX = getAcceleration_X();
  if (accelerationX>=0){
    UART_OutString("\r\nX Axl: ");
    UART_OutUDec((unsigned short) accelerationX);
  } else {
    UART_OutString("\r\nX Axl: - ");
    UART_OutUDec((unsigned short) (accelerationX*-1));
  }
}
```

Such type of code I got on some forum.
I'm not understanding why " accelerationX*-1 " is done when acceleration is negative.

Comment: `accelerationX*-1` is just obscure representation of `-accelerationX`

Answer (score 0):

`accelerationX` is a signed integer, but it would seem that `UART_OutUDec` expects an unsigned integer. Therefore they have to print a minus sign followed by the absolute value of `accelerationX` (sign removed).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the number is being sent as an unsigned short instead of a signed quantity. It would be helpful to see what `UART_OutUDec` is doing, but it also doesn't really matter because a UART will simply send whatever is dropped in its data register. As an aside, `UART_OutUDec` is most likely translating the unsigned short into ASCII. The receiver is unlikely to understand the value was supposed to be negative, so the minus sign is transmitted with what's effectively the absolute value of the acceleration.

Something to consider is that not all receivers are equal. A lot of people assume the device on the other end is a computer or something that understands ASCII, but that's not always the case. I've worked on embedded systems that transmitted ASCII characters mixed with non-ASCII characters, which is confusing and hard to maintain, but these systems exist. That's almost certainly not applicable to your situation simply because it's rare, but, in the future, if you give additional details about the receiver it will help clarify how the data should be formatted and transmitted.

Comment: In case the output is ASCII to be displayed in a terminal, the data types do matter. I suspect this is the case here, otherwise the UART routines would merely take an array of raw data bytes.

Comment: I know that and it doesn't change anything I said. A UART will send irrespective of data type, so it's up to the user to deal with typing, which is why I said the receiver is unlikely to understand a negative value given the existence of the control structure in the first place. Also, OutUDec is obviously translating the unsigned short into ASCII, which is why the code isn't using a raw transmit function.